# How do I check if a cell is blank in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through an array and any element with a value I want to print in a list going down. However, I am having problems with identifying blank cells. Right now it recognizes every cell as not be empty.  I am also including a screenshot of the data to help. (Some of the columns are hidden in the screen shot)

[image: An example]

I have tried:

Evaluate("isblank(" & Cells(i, 8).Address & ")")

IsEmpty(list(i, 1))

IsNull(list(i, 1))

None of the options above work and this is what I currently have

```
Dim list As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim Y As String
Dim X As Integer

Y = "A"
X = 2

list = Range("H12:H158").Value

For i = 1 To 147
    If Not IsEmpty(list(i, 1)) Then
        Cells(X, Y) = list(i, 1)
        X = X + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Cells containing a zero length string aren't Empty.  Try`list(i, 1) <> vbNullString`

Comment: @chrisneilsen does that return a boolean value

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly once I removed the Not.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried out your macro and as a result, in the column "A", starting from row 2, I have the values:

```
HRT-2-11
HRT-2-13
HRT-2-14
HRT-2-15
HRT-2-17
HRT-2-18
```

This, I believe, is what you are looking for, isn't it? I believe that there has been a value in the cells which appear blank, but now there should be some invisible character (like a space or something). I'd advise you to check the value of such an "empty" cell and go on from there (the "immediate" window is perfect for investigations like this).

Answer (score -1):

Len() never missed a char.

If Len(list(i, 1))>0 Then
....